# How do I load a CSS based on Laravel blade parameters?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have this route:

```php
Route::get('/{language}/{housingType}/{housingUrl}', 'HousingInfoController@index');
```

example: http://localhost/project/public/es_ES/H/this-is-housing-url

Sometimes it can have a parameter like this one:
http://localhost/project/public/es_ES/H/this-is-housing-url?group=ESQ

then on my controller I check if this parameter exists:

```php
$group = '';
if ($request->input('group')) {
    $group = $request->input('group');
}
```

and send it to the view:

```php
return view('pages.HousingInfo.index', ['group' => $group]);
```

on my HousingInfo view I do:

```php
@section('group', $group)
```

also my HousingInfo view extends from a layout, that layout includes a head, its a file with title, description, meta tags and also the CSS's.
There I have a:

```php
@yield('group')
```

so I can know which parameter was sent on the URL.

My problem is I can't use yield for IF statement to show one CSS or another based on that parameter, How can I achieve that?

**This give me error:**

```php
@if(@yield('group') == 'ESQ')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/ESQ.css') }}">
@else
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
@endif
```

Comment: does `@if ($group == 'ESQ')` work?

Comment: yes it works, tough I had to pass the variables via yield so it get recognized, its confusing now

Comment: `@yield` is used to output text on the resulting HTML page. `@yield('x')` would be equivalent to something like `<?php echo 'Contents of section X' ?>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
@if (!empty($group))
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("css/$group.css") }}">
@else
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
@endif
```

**This will enable you to use multi css if your group variable is not empty, if it is then use app.css**